# Poltergeist capybara view testing taking long time when running all test in spec in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, poltergeist

I'm using capybara with poltergeist for rspec testing in ruby on rails.

We're using stripe for payment gateway.

Request to stripe in already stub and real http connections are disabled.

However when I run the spec file alone.

It passes with the following test result.

---

Can add billing information to my account

Finished in 14.27 seconds (files took 4.84 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures

---

But when I run all the test it fails due to long time delay for response and I'm getting this output.

### **Failures**:

[image]

### My code-

```
scenario "Can add billing information to my account", js: true do
    within "#top-menu" do
      click_link "ACCOUNT"
    end
    click_link "Billing"

    click_link "Add billing information"

    within "#subscription" do
      fill_in "Name", with: "John Smith"
      fill_in "Email", with: "john.smith@example.com"
      fill_in "Phone number", with: "0443 123123"
      fill_in "Company", with: "Cribber"
      fill_in "Street address", with: "14 Somewhere Street"
      fill_in "City", with: "Brisbane"
      fill_in "Postcode / Zip", with: "4000"
      fill_in "State", with: "QLD"
      select "Australia", from: "Country"
      select "Australian Dollar", from: "Currency"

      fill_in "Card number", with: "4242424242424242"
      select Time.now.year + 1, from: "card_expiry_year"
      fill_in "CVC", with: "123"

      check "subscription_billing_attributes_terms_of_service"
    end

    click_button "Subscribe"
    expect(page).to have_content("Thank you for subscribing to Cribber!")
  end
```

I added sleep(200) after click_button "Subscribe".But it showed the following result.

[image]

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance for helping.

I tried changing http://localhost to http://127.0.0.1 in .env.test file but I got these error.

[image]

[image]

The strange thing is that if I run the spec file alone or the feature folder for view spec then I get no error message and the test pass.But if I run

> **rspec spec/** then the test fails.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is explained in your screenshot - while localhost and 127.0.0.1 point to the same place they are technically different origins.  You need to find where you're setting the app to make a request to http://localhost/... and change it to 127.0.0.1

Comment: If you're getting exactly the same error then it's still requesting from localhost, and you haven't actually fixed your error

Comment: @waliulBariAdnan I don't know what you're chaning in your .env.test file but from your picture the error is not exactly the same - the hostname now matches but the port is not being allowed - You need to read up on CORS --  and make sure whatever is listening on /admin/billing is allowing requests from the urls they're being made from.

Comment: ,Thanks.I changed DEFAULT_HOST=http://127.0.0.1.I checked rack-cors gem.But will it break the security of the web application?

Comment: If you're changing it for more than just the test environment it could -- but if you change it only when in the test environment then no